# npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to setup a simple server implementation with node, but get this error:

```
AC-MacBook-Pro:comments_box ac$ ls
bower_components    comments.json       components.jsx      index.html      node_modules        npm-debug.log
AC-MacBook-Pro:comments_box ac$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/ac/Projects/funning_around/reactjs/comments_box/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/ac/Projects/funning_around/reactjs/comments_box
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/ac/Projects/funning_around/reactjs/comments_box/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ac/Projects/funning_around/reactjs/comments_box/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Might want to format that so its easier for us to read

Answer (score 4):

package.json is missing, as the error clearly states. You should create this file. It can be done manually, but for first time `npm init` might be exactly what you need.